# Spring Hibernate Annotation for joining several tables with different relationships

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have the below setup of classes. As you can see, the connection between the entities is as follows: Passager(1-n)Buchung(n-1)Faehrfahrt(n-1)Faehre(n-1)Strecke.  I tried to implement the logic above into my hibernate setup. If I start this however (Start means: Using the gradlew build command, since my project is Spring,Gradle,Java)) I get the following error message (see the end of this), which basically says that my Understanding of 1-To-Many relationship s wrong, e.g. I try to Map a Non Collection as Collection. However, I do not see where I am doing this mistake, since for my understanding, all relationship are annotated correctly. So why does it not work?

Thanks for your help people! :)

```
@Entity
public class Buchung { 

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private UUID id;    

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne()
private Faehrfahrt faehrfahrt;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
private Passagier passagier;
```

..

```
@Entity
public class Passagier {



@Id
@GeneratedValue
private UUID id;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "buchung")
@JoinColumn(name = "passagier_id")
private ArrayList<Buchung> buchungen = new ArrayList<>();
```

..

```
@Entity
public class Faehre {    

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private UUID id;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="faehre_id")
private List<Faehrfahrt> faehrfahrten = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
private Strecke strecke;
```

..

```
@Entity
public class Faehrfahrt {

private Date zeitpunkt;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private UUID id;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
private Faehre faehre;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "buchung")
@JoinColumn(name="faehrfahrt_id")
private ArrayList<Buchung> buchungen = new ArrayList<>();
```

..

```
@Entity
public class Strecke {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private UUID id;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="strecke_id")
private List<Faehre> faehren = new ArrayList<>();
```

..

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: aiApp.applicationcore.faehrecomponent.Faehrfahrt.buchungen
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at aiApp.applicationcore.Application.main(Application.java:35) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: aiApp.applicationcore.faehrecomponent.Faehrfahrt.buchungen
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1892) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:911) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:738) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on the set-up, your configuration should look more or less like the following:

**Buchung**

```
@Entity
public class Buchung { 

   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "faehrfahrt_id")
   private Faehrfahrt faehrfahrt;

   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "passagier_id") 
   private Passagier passagier;

}
```

**Passagier**

```
@Entity
public class Passagier {

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "passagier")
   private List<Buchung> buchungen = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Faehre**

```
@Entity
public class Faehre {    

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="faehre")
   private List<Faehrfahrt> faehrfahrten = new ArrayList<>();

   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "strecke_id")
   private Strecke strecke;

}
```

**Faehrfahrt**

```
@Entity
public class Faehrfahrt {

   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "faehre_id")
   private Faehre faehre;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "faehrafhrt")
   private List<Buchung> buchungen = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**Strecke**

```
@Entity
public class Strecke {

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="strecke")
   private List<Faehre> faehren = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: After applying your changes, I do still get the same error message

Comment: Try to change the type To List ... not ArrayList

Comment: Ok great stuff.